# Proving $A+2B+3C+4D < 2.5$ with given conditions

Tags: inequality

I want to prove follow inequality.

Conditions:

$$A+B+C+D=1$$

$$A>B>C>D>0$$

Prove: $$A+2B+3C+4D < 2.5$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&A>D,~B>C\\
\Rightarrow &3A+B>C+3D\\
\Rightarrow &A+2B+3C+4D<2.5(A+B+C+D)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using more variables: Put $D=w,C=w+x,B=w+x+y,A=w+x+y+z$ where $w,x,y,z>0$ to reflect the assumption $A>B>C>D>0.$ Then $A+B+C+D=1$ becomes $4w+3x+2y+z=1,$ from which (since $x,y,z>0$) it follows that $w<1/4.$ Now let $E=A+2B+3C+4D$ be the objective function, which in terms of $w,x,y,z$ becomes
$$E=10w+6x+3y+z.$$
From this subtract $2=2(4w+3x+2y+z)$ and get $E-2=2w-y-z.$ So since $y,z>0$ this gives $E-2<2w<2(1/4)=1/2,$ so that as desired $E<2+1/2=2.5.$